# Why does my android app shut down overnight

Tags: android

I am still trying to understand the application life cycle of my Android App. I leave my app running in background in the night and in the morning, when I click on the app icon again, the splash screen would appear. From the log file, my Android Application is restarted. However it would still display the old activity from last night.  The weird thing is that I could only reproduce this on my phone but not on another developer's phone and I could not find if any app is doing anything special overnight:

1. It should not be due to battery saver since my phone is in charge overnight
2. It should not be due to limited memory since no one is using the phone overnight

Any one has a good link about Application life cycle (not Activity life cycle) on Android?

Comment: Can you provide more detail about what your app is doing, what components make it up (just Activities, or also Services, BroadcastReceivers, etc.)

Comment: Yes, besides Activity, we do have Intent Services and BroadcastReceivers, so the app is running at background. It monitors network connection change as well. Generally my phone is at the airplane mode overnight. There is no crash in my app, otherwise I would see the stack trace.

Comment: If your services are completely Intent based and nothing is firing Intents to them, they will get destroyed unless marked as "foreground".  BroadcastReceivers are only active when the Intent it receives is fired.  Otherwise they are destroyed and if nothing else in your app is active then its process will be destroyed.

Comment: So the bottom line is that if your Activity was paused because you hit HOME to get back to the desktop, etc. and nothing else is using your Service then it can be assumed that the system decided to destroy the app process overnight.

Comment: thanks very much. It helps a lot. I guess the question would be why it doesn't happen on another developer's phone. It seems that we still could not answer this question.

Comment: It's really dependent on a lot of things...I'll elaborate as an "answer".  :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apps are made up of one or more of the components: Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver and ContentProvider.  Each one of these are run as part of your application, all within the same process.  Further, each one of these components' entry points (onCreate, onStart, etc.) runs on the main (or UI) thread of your app's process.  When your app is put into the background the process is cached and kept ready to go.  But, it is up to the framework and kernel to decide limits on this.

So the bottom of line of why your app gets destroyed on one device and not the other is: it depends on the device and on what is running on the device.  The Linux kernel running under the Android framework is told what process "limits" are in play for memory resources and the ActivityManager framework component notifies the kernel when a given process is of a certain type.  For example, a simple app with just an Activity gets a certain limit and priority (from a process killer perspective, not scheduler).  Another app which uses an Activity plus a Service which is marked as a foreground Service gets a different priority, making it "harder" to kill off.  The "what is running on the device" part of the answer is just that: what other APKs are installed and active on each device.  Your device may be more memory constrained or you could have other apps which have foreground services trying to access the network often, etc.  So the Activity/Service/BroadcastReceiver/ContentProvider lifecycle is important as it dictates when your app's overall process is destroyed.

Comment: Is there an order of methods the app will call when the framework/kernel decide to kill the app?

Comment: No. When the app is killed off for reclaim of resources it is just sent a signal and is destroyed. There is no corresponding life cycle event.